# How can I detect whether an unlisted buffer contains a new file or an existing file?

Tags: vimscript, buffers

Upon opening a new file in an active buffer in the current window, the message line at the very bottom of the screen shows `"%f" [New File]`.

How does Vim know that the buffer contains a new file, rather than an existing file? I want to detect this in order to test whether quickfix has correctly parsed a file name from an error message. Since `getqflist()` gives `'bufno'` instead of `'filename'`, I can't use `filereadable()` for this.

I've also tried checking `getbufvar()` but until you actually try to [jump to the error with `:cc`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix), any buffers created by quickfix after parsing an error message for a file name are unlisted and `getbufvar()` returns an empty dictionary. I want to determine whether the buffer will contain a new or existing file and intervene *before* jumping to the error and opening the file.

Answer (score 3):

The [list of built-in functions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#functions) includes `bufname`, which can retrieve the filename displayed in the output of `ls!` from an unlisted buffer, before/without listing it:

> ```
> bufname( {expr})      String  Name of the buffer {expr}
> ```

So, if you know the number of the buffer, you can use `filereadable()` as in the following example:

```
let qflist = getqflist()
for item in qflist
    let readable = filereadable(bufname(item.bufnr))
    echo bufname(item.bufnr) . " is " . (readable ? "" : "not ") . "a readable file."
endfor
```